# Using different logo for different pages

Tags: css, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I would like to know if there is any way to display different logos on different pages in same site. I am using Neve theme and following is the header file content.

```
$header_classes = apply_filters( 'nv_header_classes', 'header' );
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>

<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<?php if ( is_singular() && pings_open( get_queried_object() ) ) : ?>
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>

</head>
<body  <?php body_class(); ?> <?php neve_body_attrs(); ?> >
<?php wp_body_open(); ?>
<div class="wrapper">
<?php neve_before_header_wrapper_trigger(); ?>
    <header class="<?php echo esc_attr( $header_classes ); ?>" role="banner">
    <a class="neve-skip-link show-on-focus" href="#content" tabindex="0">
        <?php echo __( 'Skip to content', 'neve' ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
    </a>
    <?php
    neve_before_header_trigger();
    if ( apply_filters( 'neve_filter_toggle_content_parts', true, 'header' ) === true ) {
        do_action( 'neve_do_header' );
    }
    neve_after_header_trigger();
    ?>
</header>
<?php neve_after_header_wrapper_trigger(); ?>
<?php do_action( 'neve_before_primary' ); ?>

<main id="content" class="neve-main" role="main">

<?php
 do_action( 'neve_after_primary_start' );
```

I used this code to display logo

```
if (is_page (‘jumbo-collection’ ))
{echo '<img src="https://carattere.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/jumboc.jpg">';}
else
{echo '<img src="https://carattere.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/jumbogrouplogo201903.jpg">';}
```

but this code is displaying both logos. Also I am not sure where to put the code in header.php file.

Waiting for the responses
Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `is_page()` function for your condition to display logos.

**Example:**

```
<?php if(is_page('PAGE1')) { ?>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
<?php } elseif(is_page('PAGE2')) { ?>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/logo2.png" alt="Logo2">
<?php } ?>
```

Or you can specify the page id number of the page you want to display the logo.

```
is_page(21) -> ID number of the page.
```

**UPDATED**

```
<?php if(is_page('etro-home-interiors')) { ?>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('carattere.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/33.png');?>/…" alt="Logo">
<?php } elseif(is_page('gianfranco-ferre')) { ?>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('carattere.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/03-1.png');?>/…" alt="Logo2">
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I used this code

<?php if(is_page('etro-home-interiors')) { ?>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('https://carattere.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/33.png');?>/images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
<?php } elseif(is_page('gianfranco-ferre')) { ?>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('https://carattere.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/03-1.png');?>/images/logo2.png" alt="Logo2">
<?php} 

but now the WordPress is giving this error:
syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end of file


How to solve this error?

Comment: It's because there is no closing tag after your php tag. I've updated the answer for your code.